# Setup tests that use the Azure storage emulator in Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, testing, azure, azure-devops

I have a project with the code hosted in Azure DevOps and I'd like to start using the Pipelines feature to handle the builds.

My first problem is that I have a set of tests that use Azure storage emulator (I'm using Azure storage in my project). These tests fail on the build server, since there is no storage emulator in there.

What would be the recommended way to proceed?

1. Configure the tests to run with a real Azure Storage account.
2. Install the emulator somehow during the build (not sure if this is
   possible).
3. Other.

Please note that I don't want to mock the interfaces and not use the Azure storage in the test implementation.

Thanks.

Comment: *"These tests fail on the build server, since there is no storage emulator in there"* - for what reason is it not there? *Install the emulator somehow during the build*  - why "during the build"? Who has the control what is preinstalled on your build server?

Comment: @DocBrown Your questions are part of my my question. I don't have experience with Azure DevOps pipelines (the build server is not my server), so I'm asking how to approach this. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so this is seems to be a question for the [Azure DevOps support](https://azure.microsoft.com/support/devops/). You should ask them there, since customer support questions for specific products or services are [not welcome here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions).

Comment: I think its a good question. No doubt there a dozen ways of doing it, the question is looking for an expert answer from someone who has tried it out and can summerise how to best fit the azure toolset into the SDLC and CD

Comment: although.... what about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723795/azure-devops-hosted-build-controller-is-the-azure-storage-emulator-supported

Comment: @Ewan Thanks, there seem to be some useful point in there. I was reluctant to ask the question on SO since it seemed to be more of the "best practices" kind of question.

Comment: We heavily discourage people to ask on this site for "braindead best practices". But your question is not such a one, it is a focussed question for a specific problem - using/installing a specific tool / service (and as the SO answer found by @Ewan shows, this is just a question on how to use a tool, not about the SDLC). Such questions can be asked on SO, but they are often better asked directly on in the support forum of the tool vendor. In this case, however, the Azure support page seems to contains a link to Stackoverflow, so they also recommend to ask there.

Comment: Id say 90% of the questions here are "best practices"

Comment: @DocBrown You're framing my question in an incorrect way by only referring to point 2 from the text. I was hoping to find someone here that had the same issue (running tests that use Azure storage in an Azure Devops build) and to find out how they solved it and if they considered at least the options I listed. I believe you see the difference. 

Also, as Ewan mentioned, I was under the impression this is the best place to ask about best practices.

Comment: @Paul: you probably missed my point. It is really **good** that your question focusses on a real problem of yours. This site is not a good place to ask for "best practices", see [this meta post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/why-questions-about-the-correct-way-are-too-broad).